# Библиотека JSOUP

Tags: java, jsoup

Всем привет!
хотел распарсить вес список статьи с сайта (имя статьи и ссылку)
Ссылка сайта-
[Ccылка на сайт](http://xn--90aw5c.xn--c1avg/index.php?title=%D0%A1%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%3A%D0%A3%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%83%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F&prefix=&namespace=0)

вот мой рабочий код

```
//мэп для сохр имя статьи и ссылку
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    // maim URL
    String url = "http://xn--90aw5c.xn--c1avg/index.php?";


    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append(url)
            .append("title=").append(URLEncoder.encode("Служебная", "UTF-8"))
            .append("%3").append(URLEncoder.encode("AУказатель", "UTF-8"))
            .append("+").append(URLEncoder.encode("по", "UTF-8"))
            .append("+").append(URLEncoder.encode("началу", "UTF-8"))
            .append("+").append(URLEncoder.encode("названия", "UTF-8"))
            .append("&prefix=&namespace=0");

    //вывод полный ссылку на сайт
    System.out.println(builder.toString());



    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url + "title=Служебная%3AУказатель+по+началу+названия&prefix=&namespace=0").userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
            .referrer("http://www.google.com").get();

    Elements linksElements = doc.select("table.mw-prefixindex-list-table").select("tbody").select("tr");
    System.out.println("linksElements = " + linksElements.size());
    List<String> links = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Element tr : linksElements) {
        Elements td = tr.select("td");
        for (Element tdLinks : td) {
            links.add(tdLinks.select("a").attr("abs:href"));
        }
    }

    //вывод на черный экран links and titles
    for (String link : links) {
        System.out.println("Link: " + link);
        Document article = Jsoup.connect(link).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
                .referrer("http://www.google.com").timeout(10000).get();
        String title = article.select("h2.title").text();
          System.out.println("title = " + title);
        map.put(link, title);
    }
```

и этот код парсит только одну страницу, а мне надо перейти на следующую страницу 
и заново парсит список статьи , и до конца!

Как мне сделать через рекурсивный метод или что -то  чтобы получить в Map-e весь ссылку на статьи

Comment: Так сделайте цикл.Переходите по ссылке на нужную страницу. Ищите нужную информацию на странице и парсите ее, затем ищите ссылку перехода на следующую стнаницу и переходите в начало цикла.

Comment: аха, спасибо уже разобрался))